# make a field visible in Edit Properpties form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column

I have added Comments field to a document library (list.Fields.Add(..)) in event receiver however when I a try to edit a document within this document library by chosing "Edit properties" the comment fields is not visible. How can I make Comments field visible in Edit Properties form? programmatically. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

On the SPField object, you can use the ShowInEditForm property to get/set whether or not to show it on the default Edit form.  See MSDN for the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showineditform.aspx

Comment: I have tested the solution, it does not working. I think it is something special with comments field because all other fields show up in edit form.

Answer (score 2):

If the document library is using content types, then you need to add the field to the contenttypes in the library

Comment: I adde a fieldlink to the content type which the library uses but not working. i think it is something special with comments field because all other fields show up in edit from.